# How should the 'System Use' field be interpreted in a 'Directory Record'?

Tags: specifications, iso9660

In the ECMA 119 specifications (freely available [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-119.htm)), I am trying to understand how to fetch the content of the `System Use` field:

[image]

How is one supposed to compute the length of the `System Use` field, i.e. how is the value of the `LEN_SU` found in the left column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `LEN_SU` is given implicitly. From BP1 you know the total number of bytes in the directory record (`LEN_DR`). `LEN_SU` is then given (implicitly) as the bytes remaining in the directory record after `33+LEN_FI+possible_padding(1)`, where you get length `LEN_FI` from BP33.

Hence

```
LEN_SU = LEN_DR - (33+LEN_FI+possible_padding(1))
```

From the spec.:

> **Padding Field [BP (34 + LEN_FI)]**
>
> This field shall be present in the
>   Directory Record **only if the number in the Length of the File
>   Identifier field is an even number**.
>
> **System Use [BP (LEN_DR - LEN_SU + 1) to LEN_DR)**
>
> This field shall be
>   optional. If present, this field shall be reserved for system use. Its
>   content is not specified by this Standard. If necessary, so that **the
>   Directory Record comprises an even number of bytes, a (00) byte shall
>   be added to terminate this field**.

Comment: Thanks for that enlightenment :D

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm working on new engine for Wipeout @ http://www.wxx-rebirth.com/ and currently I'm looking at extracting game data :D